Sticky Footer Incorrect Placement in React
Would appreciate if someone could help me understand the problem. I have a simple webpage with MUI components, and I would like to add a sticky footer at the very bottom.
However, the footer ends up in the middle of the page with the following structure of the App.jsx:
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container component='main' sx={{ padding: '0px!important', maxWidth: '100%!important' }}>
        <Box>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </Box>
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

and the following Footer.jsx:
export default function Footer () {
  return (
    <Box
      display={'flex'}
      flexDirection={'column'}
      width={'100vw'}
      height={'100vh'}
      component={'footer'}
     >
       <Box
         height={'200px'}
         display={'flex'}
         justifyContent={'center'}
         alignItems={'center'}
         sx={{ backgroundColor: '#333' }}
       >
         <Typography> © 2023 DS </Typography>
       </Box>
     </Box>
  )
}

This is how it looks like:

When I move Footer.jsx to the Home.jsx, the footer ends up at the bottom where it should be.
Home.jsx
export default function Home () {
  return (
    <Box
      display={'flex'}
      flexDirection={'column'}
      height={'100vh'}
      width={'100vw'}
    >
      <Hero />
      <Slider />
      <Logos />
      <Services />
      <Banner />
      <Portfolio />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
    </Box>
  )
}

And this is how it should look like:

Why placing <Footer /> component in the App.jsx does not work in the same way?
How can this be fixed so that Footer is in the App?
EDIT: Sandbox code is here.
I tried adding display={flex} into the App.jsx, I also tried marginTop and minHeight as per suggestions in other posts.

Inside of the Home component you're defining flex styles on Box:
<Box
  display={'flex'}
  flexDirection={'column'}
  height={'100vh'}
  width={'100vw'}
>

These properties you've added - specifically display={flex} and flexDirection={column} - are telling the page to stack everything nested inside of it vertically. Your App component has no such styles.
Edit: If you wanted to include the footer in your App component you would need something like this, apply flex styles to a wrapper around your header/footer/everything else:
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div styles={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <Header />
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Container component='main' sx={{ padding: '0px!important', maxWidth: '100%!important' }}>
          <Box>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </Box>
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      <Footer />
    </div>    
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}


Yes, for this reason, I added a Box wrapper with display={flex} in the Footer component.

That will position the content within the footer - but it won't position the footer relative to the other elements.

Thank you. I added the same styles to App as you indicated, but still, the position is the same as in the first screenshot.

If you're able to put this into a code sandbox example that will make debugging easier.

The sandbox example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-rumple-2wq75q?file=/src/Home.jsx. I have added a long list of numbers to illustrate that the footer does not move to the bottom.

Hi @JSzum - can you double check that sandbox? I'm not able to load it.

I have updated the link in the question, try that one, it should be working.

@JSzum - In Home.jsx you have a fixed height of height={"100vh"} on Box. See forked sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-rumple-2wq75q?file=%2Fsrc%2FHome.jsx

Sorry - reference this sandbox instead https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/icy-lake-k75z94

If we inspected the page, you'll notice that the root div is actually taking only 100vh, and the reset of the content in the home is just overflowing:

Looking at the Home Component, you'll see that a fixed height is given to it which is causing the content to overflow and the default value for overflow is visible if we set overflow="hidden", you'll see that the footer is actually at the bottom. But we also need to see the content, so we shouldn't set the height to a fixed value since we want the content to determine the height of the box (the default height value is auto which is what we need ).
Removing the fixed height given to the Box in the Home component will resolve the issue as the content will not overflow and will push the footer to its correct position at the bottom.
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box
      display={"flex"}
      flexDirection={"column"}
      height={"100vh"} //remove this declaration
      width={"100%"}
    >
      This is home page
      {[...Array(100).keys()].map((item, i) => (
        <Box key={i}>{item}</Box>
      ))}
      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </Box>
  );
}

here the root div has expanded because the height of the Box in the Home component became auto.

